# search for a string , and add if it matches

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I have a file that has 2 columns as given below....

```
101   6
102   23
103   45
109   36
101   42
108   21
102   24
109   67
```

and so on......

I want to write a script that adds the values from 2nd column if their corresponding first column matches

```
for example add all 2nd column values if it's 1st column is 101
add all 2nd column values if it's 1st colummn is 102
add all 2nd column values if it's 1st colummn is 103 and so on ...
```

i wrote my script like this , but i'm not getting the correct result

```
awk '{print $1}' data.txt > col1.txt
while read line
do
    awk ' if [$1 == $line] sum+=$2; END {print "Sum for time stamp", $line"=", sum}; sum=0' data.txt
    done < col1.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{array[$1]+=$2} END { for (i in array) {print "Sum for time stamp",i,"=", array[i]}}' data.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash :

```
declare -a sum
while read -a line ; do
  (( sum[${line[0]}] += line[1] ))
done < "$infile"

for index in ${!sum[@]}; do
  echo -e "$index ${sum[$index]}"
done
```

The output:

```
101 48
102 47
103 45
108 21
109 103
```